# Why is (dot) used in arguments for parameters?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently trying to learn swift and I am a bit confused to why some arguments are written with a dot before it and some don't. For example

To add a button to a UIAlertView object

alert's name = simpleAlert

buttons title = "YES"

button's style = Default

handler = nil

why is the appropriate way to write this is

```
simpleAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"YES",style: .Default, handler: nil))
```

instead of

```
simpleAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"YES",style: Default, handler: nil))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a short way of writing `UIAlertActionStyle.Default` (`UIAlertActionStyle` being an enum and `Default` being a value of it). The `UIAlertView` already knows you are gonna use a `UIAlertActionStyle` for that parameter so you can just write that enum's value.

Answer (score 1):

```
simpleAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"YES",style: .Default, handler: nil))
```

can also be written  as a

```
 simpleAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"YES",style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default
, handler: nil))
```

UIAlertActionStyle is the Enum

```
enum UIAlertActionStyle : Int {

    case Default
    case Cancel
    case Destructive
}
```

so .Default is just a simplification which means Enum type is Already given we just have to pass the proper case which we want to use.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, that is a shorthand for UIAlertActionStyle.Default.

Skipping the name of the enum and simply listing the value (`.Default` instead of `UIAlertActionStyle.Default`) is an example of Swift "type inference".

Type inference means that if the compiler can infer (figure out) the type of some value/parameter, you don't have to state it explicitly. In the example above, the value you provide for `style` must be a value of type UIAlertActionStyle, so you can skip that part.